# How to PIVOT SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
id   INT,
dsc  CHAR(30)
)


INSERT INTO @table VALUES (111, 'desc-111-01')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (111, 'desc-111-02')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (111, 'desc-111-03')

INSERT INTO @table VALUES (222, 'desc-222-01')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (222, 'desc-222-02')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (222, 'desc-222-03')
```

I need to pivot it this way

```
111 | DESC-111-01 DESC-111-02 DESC-111-03.....
222 | DESC-222-01 DESC-222-02 DESC-222-03.....
```

Thank you,
BBDS

Comment: what is your rdbms? What have you tried? There are lot of pivot example around

Comment: RDBMS - SQL Server 2016 Management Studio. I saw many examples, still cannot figure out my situation.

Comment: No, your IDE is Management Studio. Are you using SQL Server? If so, run `SELECT @@version` and that will tell you what your actual database version is.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU1) (KB4135048) - 13.0.5149.0 (X64)   May 19 2018 09:41:57   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )

Comment: Show us what have you tried and what problems you have. This isnt a free code service.

Comment: Are those values all in one column or different columns?

Comment: It looks like he's looking for a simple `PIVOT`.   Follow the link and try some of the suggestions. There are numerous pivoting examples on Google. It may take a second to wrap your head around, but once you see how it works, it's not overly difficult to grasp.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is exactly as you have shown (I mean it follows the pattern of having 3 description per ID), then:

```
select id, 
max(case when rowNo = 1 then dsc else '' end) as dsc1,
max(case when rowNo = 2 then dsc else '' end) as dsc2,
max(case when rowNo = 3 then dsc else '' end) as dsc3
from  
(select id, dsc, 
  row_number() over (partition by id order by dsc) as rowNo from @table) tmp
group by id;
```

[Here is the sample in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5bf03/1/0)